# Sum of two polynomials in multi-index notation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials

Let $p_1 = (1+x_1 +x_2)^2$ and $p_2 = (x_1+2x_2)^3$. The problem is to write $p_1+p_2$ in multi-index notation. That is as the sum $\sum_{\vert\alpha\vert\leq m}a_{\alpha}x^{\alpha}.$ The number $m$ is three, since we have at most terms of degree 3. Is it possible to determine a neat solution for the coefficient $a_{\alpha}$ besides computing each term individually? Does it maybe have to do with the binomial coeffcient?

Comment: If you want to know the coefficients $a_\alpha$, then you will always have to do some computation... To speed things up you could apply the binomial theorem, as you suggested yourself, to $p_1$ and $p_2$ in order to find their coefficients.

Comment: I did compute them. However, I dont see what the point of the problem then is. My solution would have list of co-efficients, instead of a clear definition for the co-effcient.

Comment: I think this problem is just meant as an exercise for understanding the multi-index notation, nothing more... So a list of coefficients is just fine :)